# cant get gps if i refresh within about 6 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps

im trying to get the users gps with geolocation. First of all, it takes under a second to get my GPS when i run this code. However, if i refresh the page, it might take 10 seconds, it might never show at all.

Ive found a somewhat safe waiting time is about 6 seconds after opening the browser page to then refresh it and nearly all the time it will show instantly again.

Here is the code im running anyway:

```
console.log("going into function!");
if (navigator.geolocation){

    console.log("geo is supported!");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {

        console.log("Its got the coords!");

        var lat = location.coords.latitude;
        var long = location.coords.longitude;

        console.log(lat + ", " + long);
    });
}else{
    console.log("not supported!");
}
```

The console logs were my way of debugging, It always goes into the function and tells me geo is supported so its not like my script is stuck or something. Its definitely the function.

Comment: It is a callback, so you do not need to refresh. Please check also the errors (the second parameter of `getCurrentPosition`_, you are missing such case, so it will print nothing but it will execute the function. And eventually change the options (timeouts).

Comment: sure i dont need to refresh but refreshing any webpage should restart everything. Its almost like its still loading from the last page. Also tried it with a function to handle the errors and nothing is thrown.